# How do I add code folds for specific versions in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, version-control

As a disclaimer, I'm fairly new to Netbeans and wasn't sure exactly how to phrase this question.

I have two versions of the same application.  The only difference is a few functions in several different files.  Is there an option to remove tagged code folds on export?  For example:

```
/* @Version2 Only */
function version2Function {
   //code
}
```

Or is some kind of version control the best option?  It's a real pain to go through and manually add these in with each update. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use svn. And create the branch.

Answer (score 0):

The one which we have been using is Git (as a version control) about annotations which gets added on the function, those are called 'docblocks'.

as far as I understand your question, you want to use version control system and want to know if there are any changes?

Once you use git and use netbeans with reference to that source, it lets you know of any changes by showing a color mark (like blue or green) on left panel, right next to line numbers...

You dont have to configure your netbeans for it.

So... use git on your code (Google for good tutorials) and get started... then, you do not have to worry about different versions :)

Hope this helps.